# Default date in a Form (symfony2)

Tags: forms, symfony

I create a form like this with Symfony2:

```
$builder
                ->add('days', 'date', array(
                    'widget' => 'choice',
                                    'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                                    'pattern' => '{{ day }}-{{ month }}-{{ year }}',
                                    'years' => range(Date('Y'), 2010),
                                    'label' => 'Inactive participants since',
                                    'input' => 'string',
                    ));
```

But I want to display a default date, for exemple today, so, when I print de form I see

> 02 - 05 - 2012

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this working for date?

```
 $builder
                    ->add('days', 'date', array(
                        'widget' => 'choice',
                                        'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                                        'pattern' => '{{ day }}-{{ month }}-{{ year }}',
                                        'years' => range(Date('Y'), 2010),
                                        'label' => 'Inactive participants since',
                                        'input' => 'string',
                                        'data'  => '01-01-2001'
                        ));
```

Comment: it is not working - 'Expected argument of type "\DateTime", "string" given'

Comment: @Asuraya if you get that, you haven't set it to use a `string`. In that case, use: `array('data'=>new \DateTime())`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the default date before the form.

When you create your entity (`$entity = new Entity();`), just add your default value like this:

`$entity->setDays(my_value);`

And if you want to add today's date you can use the DateTime function like this:

`$entity->setDays(new \DateTime());`

Hope i'm clear enough.

Comment: The point is how to do it without a class (entity) associed to this form. Any idea?

Comment: Good question, i'm not sure but you can try as this exemple : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class and add your default value like this `$defaultData = array('days' => new \DateTime());`

Answer (score 0):

For 2.1, the form will default to today's date with:

```
 $builder
                    ->add('days', 'date', array(
                        'widget' => 'choice',
                                        'format' => 'dd-MM-yyyy',
                                        'pattern' => '{{ day }}-{{ month }}-{{ year }}',
                                        'years' => range(Date('Y'), 2010),
                                        'label' => 'Inactive participants since',
                                        'input' => 'string',
                                        'data'  => date_create()
                        ));
```